# How can I test domain credentials against multiple machines simultaneously?

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain, remote, windows, credentials

How to test domain credentials against multiple hosts in a subnet/domain taking into account that `WMI` is allowed for remote access and no firewalls on local machines are enabled?

I need something like VMware vCenter Protect there you can choose machine group, assign credentials and test the supplied credentials and get summary why it didn't work for specific machine?

Is there something similar built-in into OS?

Answer (score 0):

I think the general idea is that since you're talking about parallelism, you need something multithreaded. Powershell could do this easily with either jobs or workflows, but 2003 is an old operating system so you'd be limited to PS 2. (Of course you could also whip something up in .NET.) Here's a very basic example:

```
Foreach($_ in $ComputersFile)
{
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock { Get-WMIObject Win32_ComputerSystem -Computer $_ -Credential $Creds }
}
```

The jobs will run in parallel.  Once all the jobs are finished, use Receive-Job to gather the results.